# How to use ArcGIS Server JavaScript API inside a <form> tag?

Tags: html, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I need to embed an ArcGIS Server JavaScript API (version 4) map in a client's Content Management System. For reasons unknown to me, the CMS developers said this results in the map's entire DOM being placed inside a `<form>` tag.

Doing so prevents the map from loading and displaying, although the JS appears to run correctly.

I've put together a simple demonstration at https://codepen.io/slead/pen/QWWedvd - if you comment/uncomment the `<form>` tag you can see that placing the map inside the form results in the map not displaying, even though the console logs show that the JS has run.

```
<!--HTML-->
<body>
  <form>
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>
  </form>
</body>

// JavaScript
require(["esri/Map", "esri/views/MapView"], function(Map, MapView) {
  console.log("Before");
  var map = new Map({basemap: "streets"});
  var view = new MapView({
    container: "viewDiv",
    map: map,
    zoom: 4,
    center: [15, 65]
  });
  console.log("After");
});
```

How can I enable the map functionality when the map's elements are located inside a `<form>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually after all that, this problem was simpler than expected. Giving the form the appropriate CSS seems to solve the problem:

```
#viewDiv, #frmMap {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

<form id="frmMap">
  <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</form>
```